# href vs routerLink, ¿Qué significa perder el estado?

Tags: angular, router, href, routerlink

Tengo una duda sobre el *href* de la etiqueta `<a>` y el *routerLink* que proporciona *Angular*.

Sé que *href* recarga la página, por lo que se pierde el estado, y que *routerLink* no recarga la página, por lo que no pierdes ningún estado.

Mi duda es la siguiente:

Si tengo una sección de mi aplicación que es una tienda online y guardo productos en 'añadir al carrito' (supongamos que esta funcionalidad la tengo hecha en un servicio),
y luego hago click en la pestaña 'home' del *navbar* (*with href*), ¿Perderé los datos?.

Es decir, ¿Los productos de 'añadir al carrito' se me borrarían?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependerá de cómo guardes ese carrito: si simplemente lo tienes en una variable de tu servicio, al reiniciar todo (al recargar la página) lo perderás. Si el servicio usa cookies o localStorage para guardar esa información de un modo menos volátil, podrás recuperarla.

Mi consejo es que no uses href porque el concepto/objetivo de SPA (Single Page Application) que se persigue al usar Angular se pierde.

Comment: con localStorage de js se pueden guardar variables hasta que se reinicie el navegador te dejo esta pagina https://itelisoft.com/como-utilizar-el-localstorage-en-angula/